# Angular: Unable to input data in text fields

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-ngmodel

Good Day, I'm using Angularjs 1.6.4 v with C# at back-end and I'm still new to this technology and learning.

Problem: I'm unable to input data in the text fields as given below.

```
<div layout="row" layout-xs="column">
                            <md-input-container class="md-icon-float md-block" flex>
                                <label>Name</label>
                                <md-icon md-font-icon="ion-ios-search"></md-icon>
                                <input ng-model="filter.name" type="text" ng-change="refreshContactTable()" ng-model-options='{ debounce: 500 }'>
                            </md-input-container>
                            <md-input-container class="md-icon-float md-block" flex>
                                <label>Contact No</label>
                                <md-icon md-font-icon="ion-ios-search"></md-icon>
                                <input ng-model="filter.contactNo" type="text" ng-change="refreshContactTable()" ng-model-options='{ debounce: 500 }'>
                            </md-input-container>
                            <md-input-container flex>
                                <label>Properties</label>
                                <md-icon md-font-icon="ion-ios-search"></md-icon>
                                <input ng-model="filter.property" type="text" ng-change="refreshContactTable()" ng-model-options='{ debounce: 500 }'>
                            </md-input-container>
                        </div>
```

I'm using Material angular as you can see my input fields are connected with ng-model which has filter function and it connect with resource services (model). Okay here is my angular code given below (ignore the property field)

```
$scope.landlordsTable = new ngTableParams(
                {
                    page: 1,
                    count: 20,
                    filter: {
                        name: "",
                        contactNo: ""
                    }
                },
                {
                    getData: function ($defer, params) {
                        ContactsResourceService.get({
                            type: 'Landlord',
                            name: params.filter().name,
                            contactNo: params.filter().contactNo,
                            page: params.page(),
                            count: params.count()
                        }, function (data) {
                            if (data) {
                                params.total(data.total);
                                $defer.resolve(data.collection);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

            $scope.refreshContactTable = function () {
                $scope.landlordsTable.reload();
            }
```

Can anyone help me to sort out this issue. Thank you.